# Copying multiple files using Python in Windows

Tags: python, pandas, windows

I have a DataFrame containing columns for source addresses, destination addresses, and filenames. I would like to know how to efficiently copy multiple files from the source addresses to the corresponding destination addresses using Python. Could you please guide me on how to use commands within Python code to accomplish this task? Additionally, I would appreciate a suggestion for an appropriate command that can copy multiple files in one go.

The expectation was to successfully copy all the files from the source addresses to their corresponding destination addresses in an efficient manner. The goal was to identify an optimal command that could copy multiple files simultaneously, reducing the overall time required for the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the basic iterative solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil

# Assuming your DataFrame is named 'df'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    source_address = row['source_address']
    destination_address = row['destination_address']
    filename = row['filename']

    # Create the full paths for the source file and the destination
    source_file_path = source_address + '/' + filename
    destination_file_path = destination_address + '/' + filename

    shutil.copy(source_file_path, destination_file_path)
```

There's no function that allows you to do it in a single efficient step, nevertheless you can parallelize this operation using threads.